# Dynamics AX 2012 - moving axc files

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012

If it helps, Dynamics 2012 is not my usual game, I am trying to help with a migration as you'll see... I have Dynamics AX 2012 clients that use configs at an older file server. They work fine, so long as they reference the old location in the registry entries that I have seen at:

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Dynamics\6.0\Configuration(Configuration File) HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Dynamics\6.0\Configuration\Original (installed configuration)\SetupProperties(Configuration File)

HKU[SID]\Software\Microsoft\Dynamics\6.0\Configuration(Configuration File) HKU[SID]\Software\Microsoft\Dynamics\6.0\Configuration\Original (installed configuration)\SetupProperties(Configuration File)

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Dynamics\6.0\Configuration(Configuration File) HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Dynamics\6.0\Configuration\Original (installed configuration)\SetupProperties(Configuration File)

I'd like to decommission the old file server referenced in the Configuration File entry. I changed the entries (referring to the new file location) for each user in HKCU on -some- computers it works, and on others I get a "Communication Error - The server is unavailable. Check your configuration and network connection and try again." On the problem users/computers, I did check to make sure that they explore the share and open the contents of the file, which does work.

So if you were moving .AXC files to a new place, what would make or break that move?

Comment: Is it simplier to just reinstall the client app to point to the new location ?

Comment: Yes and no. It presents a bigger problem for us, as we have a fair amount of post-config that we'd have to do.

Comment: Actually I found the problem - the new sharename I used in the registry was off by a space character - User error! I am going to award the answer to yagmoth, because his idea would have worked too.

Comment: @DG-PS: You can't mark comments as answers. You need to post it as an actual answer and then mark this as accepted and delete the comment.